# Error en versiones anteriores

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

No sé qué debo cambiar para que mi app sea compatible con versiones anteriores, necesito correrla en versiones 4.0.1, pero se me crashea; me sale este error:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{corpoeurekait.epaycomercios/corpoeurekait.epaycomercios.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at corpoeurekait.epaycomercios.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at corpoeurekait.epaycomercios.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_leer_qr.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200dd
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
                                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                           at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
                                                                           at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:36)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:157)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:153)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at corpoeurekait.epaycomercios.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Por favor respuesta sencilla, he googleado el error y no aparece nada parecido.

Si me pudieran explicar para que sirve el multidex, ya que si no esta habilitado se crashea, por ahi lei que es posible que sea la causa del error, pero aplico las soluciones y no se arregla el problema

Actualizo:
Aqui esta el codigo de mi LayoutInflater:

```
    //Este de abajo me aparece en rojo

    public abstract class LayoutInflater {

private static final String TAG = LayoutInflater.class.getSimpleName();
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;


protected final Context mContext;

// these are optional, set by the caller
private boolean mFactorySet;
private Factory mFactory;
private Factory2 mFactory2;
private Factory2 mPrivateFactory;
private Filter mFilter;

final Object[] mConstructorArgs = new Object[2];

static final Class<?>[] mConstructorSignature = new Class[] {
        Context.class, AttributeSet.class};

private static final HashMap<String, Constructor<? extends View>> sConstructorMap =
        new HashMap<String, Constructor<? extends View>>();

private HashMap<String, Boolean> mFilterMap;

private TypedValue mTempValue;

private static final String TAG_MERGE = "merge";
private static final String TAG_INCLUDE = "include";
private static final String TAG_1995 = "blink";
private static final String TAG_REQUEST_FOCUS = "requestFocus";
private static final String TAG_TAG = "tag";

private static final String ATTR_LAYOUT = "layout";

private static final int[] ATTRS_THEME = new int[] {
        com.android.internal.R.attr.theme };


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    boolean onLoadClass(Class clazz);
}

public interface Factory {

    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
}

public interface Factory2 extends Factory {

    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
}

private static class FactoryMerger implements Factory2 {
    private final Factory mF1, mF2;
    private final Factory2 mF12, mF22;

    FactoryMerger(Factory f1, Factory2 f12, Factory f2, Factory2 f22) {
        mF1 = f1;
        mF2 = f2;
        mF12 = f12;
        mF22 = f22;
    }

    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        View v = mF1.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
        if (v != null) return v;
        return mF2.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    }

    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        View v = mF12 != null ? mF12.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs)
                : mF1.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
        if (v != null) return v;
        return mF22 != null ? mF22.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs)
                : mF2.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    }
}

protected LayoutInflater(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}


protected LayoutInflater(LayoutInflater original, Context newContext) {
    mContext = newContext;
    mFactory = original.mFactory;
    mFactory2 = original.mFactory2;
    mPrivateFactory = original.mPrivateFactory;
    setFilter(original.mFilter);
}


public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (LayoutInflater == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
    }
    return LayoutInflater;
}


public Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}


public final Factory getFactory() {
    return mFactory;
}


public final Factory2 getFactory2() {
    return mFactory2;
}



                   Hay algunos elementos que me aparecen en rojo y la verdad ni idea de como solucionarlo, esto solo ocurre con versiones api 15
```

Elimine muchas cosas por que no me deja copiarlo completo

Comment: Fijate en tu layout del activity main en la linea 55 si no tenes algún error.Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: Jesus que bien que agregas tu LogCat para definir de una mejor forma el problema, pero en este caso como comenta Juan es importante agregues tu layout, saludos.

Comment: Cual layout agrego? por que cuando le doy click al error me abre el que esta colocado aquí